# Stopping Screen Rotation on React Native App

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm new to react native and I wanted to only allow the app to be views in portrait mode. I haven't seen anything helpful.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

To keep your application's orientation to portrait, follow below steps:

iOS:

1) Go to Xcode and open your project.
2) Select your project from navigator window.
3) select target from the target section.
4) At the top you will see general tab, select it
5) A list will open. Find Deployment Info.
6) select portrait from Device orientation list.

Android:

1) Go to Android studio and open your project.
2) Navigate to your project's AndroidManifest.xml
3) Add

```
<activity android:name=".your Activity name"//this line would be present
        android:label="@string/app_name"//this line would be present
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">//add only this line
```

Programmatically :

//Add this to your MainActivity.java (launching activity or base class)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Cheers :)